# Magento-2 Multi-select/Check box in Ui component

Tags: magento2, custom-options, uicomponent

How to change dropdown to multi-select in product page .Screenshot is attached below .
[image]

Need to change the third drop-box to multi-select or checkbox

my product_form.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="fieldname">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Available Slots</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="fieldname_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Today\Slot\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Tabs\Demo</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="fieldname2">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ADD/REMOVE SLOTS</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="customer_id"  formElement="select" component="Today_Slot/js/components/select-customer" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="mapper" xsi:type="object">Today\Slot\Model\Mapper</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <required>true</required>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
            <label translate="true">Select Slot Type</label>
            <dataScope>data.customer</dataScope>
            <componentType>field</componentType>
            <listens>
                <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
            </listens>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Today\Slot\Ui\Component\Create\Form\Customer\CustomerOptions"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
    <field name="order_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Today_Slot/js/components/select-order</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Dates</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="mapper" xsi:type="object">Today\Slot\Model\Mapper</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataScope>data.order_id</dataScope>
            <listens>
                <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
            </listens>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="order_for">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Slots</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">7</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Multiselect component provides the interface for a list or a data set. Multiselect allows selecting multiple items.

```
<form>
    ...
    <fieldset>
        ...
        <field name="multiselect_example" formElement="multiselect">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Multiselect Example</label>
                <dataScope>multiselect_example</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <multiselect>
                    <settings>
                        <options>
                            <option name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option #1</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option #2</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="3" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option #3</item>
                            </option>
                        </options>
                    </settings>
                </multiselect>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        ...
    </fieldset>
    ...
</form>
```

You can find more explaination here...
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-multiselect.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <filters name="listing_filters">
    <filterSelect name="private_group" provider="${ $.parentName }" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select" template="ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select">
    <settings>
    <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\PrivateGroup\GroupList"/>
    <caption translate="true">Select...</caption>
    <label translate="true">Private Groups</label>
    <dataScope>private_group</dataScope>
    <imports>
    <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
    </imports>
    </settings>
    </filterSelect>
    </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <column name="private_group" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customer\Groups" sortOrder="100">
    <settings>
    <dataType>select</dataType>
    <sortable>false</sortable>
    <label translate="true">Private Groups</label>
    </settings>
    </column>
    </columns>
    </listing>
```

class file

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model\PrivateGroup;

    class GroupList implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
    {
        public function toOptionArray()
        {
            $options = [];
            $options[] = ['label' => 'VIP Group', 'value' => '1'];
            $options[] = ['label' => 'Premium Type', 'value' => '2'];
            return $options;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Added this for Categories  you can change options to Yours

```
<field name="select_Categories">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
       <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
       <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
       <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
       <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">select_Categories</item>
       <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
       <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
       <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
       <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
       <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
          </item>
       </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```